# Create an XML file from an Oracle database

Tags: xml, oracle

I am working with an Oracle database. I need to create an XML file that retrieves data from some tables. I have written a query that gives me the XML result I need. See the query below.

Now, I need to:

1. Write the query in a 'script-form file', so that I can execute the file from inside my application.
2. Pass a parameter to the script file (to select the proper record I want to get the data from - in the query I provide this is the fix value 'E_0015').
3. Save the results of the query in an XML file.

How can I accomplish all of these goals?

```
select
       XMLSerialize(DOCUMENT 
       XMLElement("Gapi",
                  XMLAttributes('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as "xmlns:xsi",
                                'http://www.hmpwjb.com/gapi/WorkOrder' as "xmlns", 
                                'TIW000' as "source_reference",
                                'WorkOrder' as "name",
                                'TIW17FNQ' as "destination_reference"),
                  (
                  select XMLElement("WorkOrderHeader",
                                    XMLElement("SourceTradingPartner", 'TIW000'),
                                    XMLElement("DestinationTradingPartner", 'TIW17FNQ'),
                                    XMLElement("WorkOrder", WorkOrderHeader.WO_NUM),
                                    XMLElement("WorkOrderDescription", WorkOrderHeader.WO_DESCRIPTION),
                                    XMLElement("ResponsiblePersonID", 'Opr'),
                                    XMLElement("DivisionID", 'COUNTRY'),
                                    XMLElement("SynchIndicatorID", 'A')
                                    , (
                                    select XMLElement("WorkOrderLine",
                                                      XMLElement("WorkOrderLineReference", '0001'),
                                                      XMLElement("Item", 'ITEM_CODE'),
                                                      XMLElement("SynchIndicatorID", 'A'),
                                                      XMLElement("SubstitutePriorityMethod", 'Y')
                                                      , (
                                                      select XMLElement("WorkOrderRoutingHeader",
                                                                        XMLElement("SynchIndicatorID", 'A'),
                                                                        XMLElement("Increment", '10')
                                                                        , (
                                                                        select XMLElement("WorkOrderRouting",
                                                                                          XMLElement("SynchIndicatorID", 'A'),
                                                                                          XMLElement("Operation", '  10'),
                                                                                          XMLElement("Function", 'FUNCTION'),
                                                                                          XMLElement("OperationType", 'I'),
                                                                                          XMLElement("WorkCenter", wortg.WC)
                                                                                          , (
                                                                                          select XMLAgg(XMLElement("WorkOrderRoutingTool",
                                                                                                                   XMLForest('A' as "SynchIndicatorID",
                                                                                                                             WorkOrderRoutingTool.WO_RTOOL_SEQ as "ToolSeq",
                                                                                                                             WorkOrderRoutingTool.TOOL as "ToolID",
                                                                                                                             cast(WorkOrderRoutingTool.QTY as varchar(100)) as "ToolQuantity"))
                                                                                                        order by WorkOrderRoutingTool.WO_RTOOL_SEQ
                                                                                                       )
                                                                                          from WO_RTOOL WorkOrderRoutingTool
                                                                                          where WorkOrderRoutingTool.WO_NUM = WorkOrderHeader.WO_NUM
                                                                                            )
                                                                                         )
                                                                        from WO_HDR WorkOrderRouting
                                                                        left outer join WO_RTG wortg
                                                                           on wortg.CCN = WorkOrderRouting.CCN and wortg.MAS_LOC = WorkOrderRouting.MAS_LOC and
                                                                              wortg.WO_NUM = WorkOrderRouting.WO_NUM 
                                                                        where WorkOrderRouting.WO_NUM = WorkOrderHeader.WO_NUM
                                                                          )
                                                                        , (
                                                                        select XMLElement("WorkOrderRoutingAddendum",
                                                                                          XMLElement("SynchIndicatorID", 'A'))
                                                                        from WO_HDR WorkOrderRoutingAddendum
                                                                        where WorkOrderRoutingAddendum.WO_NUM = WorkOrderHeader.WO_NUM
                                                                          )
                                                                       )
                                                      from WO_HDR WorkOrderRoutingHeader
                                                      where WorkOrderRoutingHeader.WO_NUM = WorkOrderHeader.WO_NUM
                                                        )
                                                     )
                                    from WO_HDR WorkOrderLine
                                    where WorkOrderLine.WO_NUM = WorkOrderHeader.WO_NUM
                                      )
                                    ,(
                                    select XMLElement("WorkOrderLineAddendum",
                                                      XMLElement("SynchIndicatorID", 'A'),
                                                      XMLElement("PlanningStatus", '4'),
                                                      XMLElement("ManufacturingStatus", '2')) 
                                    from WO_HDR WorkOrderLineAddendum
                                    where WorkOrderLineAddendum.WO_NUM = WorkOrderHeader.WO_NUM
                                     )
                                   )
                  from WO_HDR WorkOrderHeader
                  where WorkOrderHeader.WO_NUM = '              E_0015'
                  )
                 )
            AS BLOB ENCODING 'utf-8' VERSION '1.0' INDENT) as "XML"
from dual;
```

Comment: How you store and execute the query, how you pass in a parameter and how you write the result to a file depend on the application you are using/writing.

Comment: Alex: we have a system that uses the Oracle database, and lives in a Linux box. We have a way to execute commands from inside our application, so I need to execute the query using that 'shell' approach. In order to use the database and test 'locally', we use Toad (where I wrote and fine tuned my query), but I can't use Toad in order to write/test the parts that I'm missing (the query file, how to pass the parameter, and how to dump the query result to the XML file). Hope this helps.

Comment: So your application is going to call a shell script, which will call SQL\*Plus (?), which will run a .sql script file - and you want to know how to pas an argument to that and write the results to a file? Does the file need to go on the DB server, or locally on the box where the shell runs?

Comment: Alex: Yes, our system can execute external SQL commands using PLSQL; so we need to use the script name and find a way to pass the parameter to the script. And the file needs to be located in the same Linux box (although this I'm not 100% sure but can always check with the DBA people). Thanks

Comment: Just as an aside, a tab indent of **eighteen spaces** makes it impossible to read your code on this site. Maybe you have super-wide monitors at work and this amount of indenting is appropriate for you. But there's just too much horizontal scrolling required of us.

Comment: Why does your application have to run parameterized shell scripts to execute a query script? Why not just connect to the database and run the SQL?

Comment: APC: sorry about the spaces. I just copied the code from my Toad session and didn't realize it would be a problem to scroll to see it in full. Regarding your question, my system could execute the SQL code if I can manage to dump the result to an XML file, so that's an option too. Thanks